I implemented Zibal payment gateway for NextJS, it gives an error zibal.init is not a function
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
const Zibal = require('zibal');

Zibal.init({
  merchant: 'zibal',
  callbackUrl: 'https://some-callback-url.tld',
  logLevel: 2
});

export async function POST(req) {
  try{
    const { amount, mobile, description } = req.json();

    try {
      const result = await Zibal.request(amount, { mobile, description });
      if (result.result === 100) {
        const paymentUrl = Zibal.startURL(result.trackId);
        return NextResponse.json({ paymentUrl },{status:200});
      } else {
        return NextResponse.json({ error: result.statusMessage },{status:400});
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
      return NextResponse.json({ error: 'Error creating payment request' },{status:500});
    }
  } catch {
    return NextResponse.json({ error: 'The method is illegal' },{status:405});
  }
}

TypeError: Zibal.init is not a function
How can I solve it? It is also written like this in the documentation of their site
